# How to remove shortcut virus from usb-flash-drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, virus, virus-removal

My usb-falsh-drive have shortcuts of every folder and even if I deleted They are remaining same.
Have any  one experienced it? How to remove or prevent it?

Thanks in advance,
Vicky

Comment: What happens when you try to delete a shortcut from your flash drive?

Comment: Run a virus scan

Comment: Format the drive.

Comment: If deleted also, shortcuts remains same when opened again. virus Scan will delete but won't prevent it. Formatted means the data will be lost . cannot plugin to any windows system , because the virus will start work ther and creating hidden folders and shortcuts.

Comment: Formatting will remove the data and any virus as well. If you are paranoid, you can delete the existing partition and recreate it, then format it. Obviously, ensure your systems are clean as well or you'll only end up eventually re-infecting the drive.

Answer (score 3):

Formatting will remove the data and any virus as well. If you are paranoid, you can delete the existing partition and recreate it, then format it.

Comment: If you're *really* paranoid, you can `dd` zeroes onto it, and then create another partition table.

Comment: If you're _really really_ paranoid, you can just throw the usb-flash-drive away :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out my USB Shortcut virus fixer batch file:

```
@echo off & title USB Virus Fixer & color 0a & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::****************************************************************
openfiles >nul 2>&1 & if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (
  setlocal disableDelayedExpansion & color 4f
  echo Running Admin Shell, Please wait.... & ping localhost -n 1 >nul
  set "bPath=%~f0" & setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 
  echo Dim UAC : Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) >Elevate.vbs
  echo For Each strArg in Wscript.Arguments >>Elevate.vbs
  echo   args = args ^& strArg ^& " " >>Elevate.vbs
  echo Next >>Elevate.vbs
  echo UAC.ShellExecute "!bPath!",args,"","runas",1 >>Elevate.vbs
  echo Set objShell = Nothing >>Elevate.vbs
  cscript //nologo Elevate.vbs & del Elevate.vbs & exit /b
)
::****************************************************************
if not exist "%userprofile%\desktop\%~n0.lnk" (
  (
  echo Call Shortcut("%~f0","USB Virus Fixer"^)
  echo Sub Shortcut(Application,Name^)
  echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
  echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
  echo    MyTab = Split(Application,"\"^)
  echo    If Name = "" Then
  echo      Name = MyTab(UBound(MyTab^)^)
  echo    End if
  echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
  echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Name ^& ".lnk"^)
  echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Chr(34^) ^& Application ^& Chr(34^)
  echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "shell32.dll,26"
  echo    objShortCut.Save
  echo End Sub
  ) >>crshort.vbs
  cscript //nologo crshort.vbs & del crshort.vbs
)
::**************************************************************
:top
mode 160,40 & cls
wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType=2" 2>f.txt >nul
set /p err=<f.txt
if "%err%"=="No Instance(s) Available." goto :No_USB
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType=2" get Caption /format:list') do set "usb=%%a"
if exist %usb% goto :USB_Before_Fix 
::**************************************************************
:USB_Before_Fix
cls & echo. & echo.
echo                          #######################################################################
echo                                     Your USB key is mounted, connected as %usb%
echo                          #######################################################################
echo.
pause >nul | echo Press any key to start fixing the USB drive.....
::**************************************************************
::USB_Fix 
cls & echo. & echo.
echo Applying Shortcut Virus Fix.....
del /f /q /s %usb%\*.lnk
attrib -a -s -h -r /s /d %usb%\*.*
ping localhost -n 2 >nul 2>&1
echo Removing suspicious virus files.....
for %%a in (ntde1ect.com semo2x.exe avpo.exe ntdelect.com ntdeiect.com amvo.exe rtlip.exe x.exe ert.dll help.exe copy.exe hello.vbs hello.wsf debug) do (
  if exist "%usb%\%%~a" (
    attrib -s -h -r "%usb%\%%~a"
    del /f /q /s "%usb%\%%~a"
  )
)
ping localhost -n 2 >nul 2>&1
::**************************************************************
::USB_After_Fix
cls & echo. & echo.
echo                          #######################################################################
echo                                        Fixing the USB drive (%usb%) was successful
echo                          #######################################################################  
echo.
explorer "%usb%"
pause >nul | echo Press any key to quit.....
exit /b 0
::**************************************************************
:No_USB
del /f /q f.txt
cls & color 0c & echo. & echo.
echo                          #######################################################################
echo                                        Your usb key is not detected, please check
echo                          #######################################################################    
echo.
pause >nul | echo Press any key to Re-Check (Alt+F4/Close button to exit)     
goto :top
```

It can auto-detect USB drives and start actions.